# Density of simple functions in Bochner space; approximation from below

Tags: functional-analysis, bochner-spaces

Let $f \in L^2(0,T;V)$ where $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$ or $V=L^2(\Omega)$.

Suppose that $|f| \leq M$ for some constant $M$ almost everywhere.

Is it possible to find a sequence of simple functions $f_n(t) = \sum_i^n \chi_{E_i}(t)w_i$ that converges to $f(t)$ such that $w_i \leq M$ for each $i$?

I.e. can $f$ be approximated from below in some sense?

Comment: When you say $|f|\leq M$, do you mean $\|f\|_V \leq M $ or $\|f\|_{L^2(0,T;V)}\leq M$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor, I'd rather suspect $\lvert f(t)\rvert\leq M$ a.e. on $\Omega$ for a.e. $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: yes @MaoWao is right

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, because cut-offs behave well for the spaces in question. Let $C\colon \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C},\,r e^{i\theta}\mapsto \min\{r,M\} e^{i\theta}$. The map
$$
V\longrightarrow V,\,f\mapsto C\circ f
$$
is continuous and $\lVert C\circ f\rVert_V\leq \lVert f\rVert_V$. That is clear for $V=L^2(\Omega)$, but maybe not so obvious for $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$. This property holds for the domain of any closed derivation such as $\nabla$ in this case.

Thus, if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of simple functions converging to $f$ pointwise or almost everywhere , then the sequence $(f_n')$ defined by $f'_n(t)=C\circ f_n(t)$ converges to $C\circ f=f$ pointwise or almost everywhere.

If you want convergence in $L^2(0,T;V)$, use the fact that you can choose an a.e. convergent subsequence and then apply the dominated convergence theorem (the inequality $\lVert C\circ f\rVert_V\leq \lVert f\rVert_V$ gives the relevant bound).